# How to properly suppress mypy error 'Name "__qualname__" not defined'

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

When using `__qualname__` as part of the python logger formatter for classes, I am getting mypy error 'Name "**qualname**" not defined'. I can suppress it with inline `# type: ignore`, but wonder if there are more proper ways to do this, or if there are ways to have mypy recognize `__qualname__`.

Comment: Looks like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6473) on mypy's github about this exact issue.